# Read a partitioned parquet dataset with filtering using dask read_parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet, pyarrow

I have a partitioned parquet dataset directory on my local machine which looks something like this:

```
dataset
|
├───_common_metadata
├───_metadata
├───travel=land
|   |
|   ├───direction=arrivals
|   |   |
|   |   ├───dayofweek=Monday
|   |   ├───dayofweek=Tuesday
|   |   ├───dayofweek=Wednesday
|   |   ├───...
|   |   └───dayofweek=Sunday
|   |
|   └───direction=departures
|       |
|       ├───dayofweek=Monday
|       ├───...
|       └───dayofweek=Sunday
|
├───travel=sea
|   |
|   ├───direction=arrivals
|   |   |
|   |   ├───dayofweek=Monday
|   |   ...
|   |
|   └───direction=departures
|       |
|       ...
|
└───travel=air
    |
    ...
```

So navigating to a particular parquet file would be:
`/dataset/travel=air/direction=departures/dayofweek=Sunday/data.part1.parquet`
`/dataset/travel=air/direction=departures/dayofweek=Sunday/data.part2.parquet`
..and so on.

The data is tabular with headers like "registration", "delayed", "passenger_count", etc.

I can load this data into a pandas dataframe with pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset and filter it like this, and it works fine:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import pandas as pd

filters = [
    ("travel", "in", ["land", "air"]),
    ("direction", "in", ["departures"]),
    ("dayofweek", "in", ["Monday", "Wednesday"]),
    ("delayed", "=", "T"),
    ("passenger_count", ">=", 100)
]

pds = pq.ParquetDataset("/path/to/dataset", filters=filters, use_legacy_dataset=False)
df = pds.read_pandas().to_pandas()
```

But, the data I have is very large and does not fit in memory so I am trying to use Dask instead of Pandas. I have the following converted code for doing the same thing as above:

```py
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import dask.dataframe as dd

filters = [
    ("travel", "in", ["land", "air"]),
    ("direction", "in", ["departures"]),
    ("dayofweek", "in", ["Monday", "Wednesday"]),
    ("delayed", "=", "T"),
    ("passenger_count", ">=", 100)
]

df = dd.read_parquet(
    "/path/to/dataset",
    filters=filters,
    engine="pyarrow",
    use_legacy_dataset=False
)
```

Running `df.info()` and `df.head(5)` after loading with dask returns the correct column names and dtypes but an empty dataframe:

```
Columns: 127 entries, sequence to expired
Empty Dataframe <-- BAD!
dtypes: object(74), float32(9), int64(44)None
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [registration, delayed, passenger_count ...]
Index: [] <-- BAD!
```

I'm trying to understand what I'm doing here. Are the filters formatted incorrectly for `dd.read_parquet()`? Are the input arguments I should provide to `dd.read_parquet()` which I am missing? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Maybe try to add filters one by one, it could be that one of them has a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say for sure, but it is possible that nothing is wrong at all. Since dask produces *lazy* objects until you explicitly reduce or compute, it only holds the minimum of metadata. In particular, when filtering, there may be partitions with no data inside. `df.head()` only fetches data from the first partition by default, so you might want to perform an operation guaranteed to read some of the data:

```
len(df)  # explicitly scan dataframe and count valid rows
```

If you still get a value of 0 out, you may want to try with the fastparquet backend; it only performs partition-filtering rather than row-filtering by default.